# Merge array of javascript objects

Tags: javascript, node.js, arrays, reactjs, javascript-objects

This is the array of javascript objects. I want these javascript objects will merge into a single javascript object according to their same property value.

This is the original array:

```
const array = [
 {email: 'jon@endtest-mail.io', name: 'Jon', role: 'Player', Education: {…}},
 {email: 'jon@endtest-mail.io', name: 'Jon', role: 'Player', Skills: {…}},
 {email: 'jon@endtest-mail.io', name: 'Jon', role: 'Player', Total: {…}},
 {email: 'jon@endtest-mail.io', name: 'Jon', role: 'Player', Personal: {…}},
 {email: 'tayyab@endtest-mail.io', name: 'Tayyab', role: 'Lead', Ethics: {…}},
 {email: 'tayyab@endtest-mail.io', name: 'Tayyab', role: 'Lead', Total: {…}},
 {email: 'arya@endtest-mail.io', name: 'Arya', role: 'Banker', Total: {…}},
 {email: 'arya@endtest-mail.io', name: 'Arya', role: 'Banker', Skills: {…}},
 {email: 'arya@endtest-mail.io', name: 'Arya', role: 'Banker', Personal: {…}},
 {email: 'arya@endtest-mail.io', name: 'Arya', role: 'Banker', Education: {…}},
]
```

This is the required array:

```
const array = [
 {email: 'jon@endtest-mail.io', name: 'Jon', role: 'Player', Education: {…}, Skills: {…}, Total: {…}, Personal: {…}},
 {email: 'tayyab@endtest-mail.io', name: 'Tayyab', role: 'Lead', Ethics: {…}, Total: {…}},
 {email: 'arya@endtest-mail.io', name: 'Arya', role: 'Banker', Total: {…}, Skills: {…}, Personal: {…}, Education: {…}},
]
```

Like email, name, and role all three have the same property and property value. It would merge into one javascript object and the others remain the same. Kindly provide the solution in **React.js/Javascript**. Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A good case to apply reduce method, try this code:

```js
const array = [
 {email: 'jon@endtest-mail.io', name: 'Jon', role: 'Player', Education: {}},
 {email: 'jon@endtest-mail.io', name: 'Jon', role: 'Player', Skills: {}},
 {email: 'jon@endtest-mail.io', name: 'Jon', role: 'Player', Total: {}},
 {email: 'jon@endtest-mail.io', name: 'Jon', role: 'Player', Personal: {}},
 {email: 'tayyab@endtest-mail.io', name: 'Tayyab', role: 'Lead', Ethics: {}},
 {email: 'tayyab@endtest-mail.io', name: 'Tayyab', role: 'Lead', Total: {}},
 {email: 'arya@endtest-mail.io', name: 'Arya', role: 'Banker', Total: {}},
 {email: 'arya@endtest-mail.io', name: 'Arya', role: 'Banker', Skills: {}},
 {email: 'arya@endtest-mail.io', name: 'Arya', role: 'Banker', Personal: {}},
 {email: 'arya@endtest-mail.io', name: 'Arya', role: 'Banker', Education: {}},
]

let result = Object.values(array.reduce((acc, {name, ...rest}) => {
    acc[name] = {...acc[name], ...{name, ...rest}};
    return acc;
}, {}));

console.log(result);
```

Comment: The end results would be an object instead of an array, but this could easily be updated to work as the question wants

Comment: @Joe Lissner result is an Array

Comment: Yup, my bad! Missed the `Object.values`

Answer (score 0):

Using reduce and Object.values

```js
const array = [
 {email: 'jon@endtest-mail.io', name: 'Jon', role: 'Player', Education: {}},
 {email: 'jon@endtest-mail.io', name: 'Jon', role: 'Player', Skills: {}},
 {email: 'jon@endtest-mail.io', name: 'Jon', role: 'Player', Total: {}},
 {email: 'jon@endtest-mail.io', name: 'Jon', role: 'Player', Personal: {}},
 {email: 'tayyab.ejaz@endtest-mail.io', name: 'Tayyab', role: 'Lead', Ethics: {}},
 {email: 'tayyab.ejaz@endtest-mail.io', name: 'Tayyab', role: 'Lead', Total: {}},
 {email: 'arya@endtest-mail.io', name: 'Arya', role: 'Banker', Total: {}},
 {email: 'arya@endtest-mail.io', name: 'Arya', role: 'Banker', Skills: {}},
 {email: 'arya@endtest-mail.io', name: 'Arya', role: 'Banker', Personal: {}},
 {email: 'arya@endtest-mail.io', name: 'Arya', role: 'Banker', Education: {}},
]

const result = Object.values(array.reduce((acc, item) => {
    // build key with unique props
    const key = [item.email, item.name, item.role].join("-");
    // assign properties to a new object
    // if object does not exist with the key it uses empty object
    acc[key] = {...(acc[key] || {}), ...item}; 
    return acc;
}, {}));

console.log(result);
```

Comment: Probably the same person that downvted the question and the other answer.

Comment: yeah it seems good to me. Have another upvote! The comments made it clearer for me to understand.